# Why 'afterInteractive' break Google Analytics to work in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-analytics

Since I replaced this:

```
<script
    async
    src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}`}
/>
```

with this:

```js
<Script
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  id="google-analytics"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
                                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                                gtag('js', new Date());   
                                gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS}');
                                `,
  }}
/>;
```

Google analytics stopped to work. What is wrong? Google Analytics console show 0 visitor for each day, and it indicate measuring is corrupted.

I took example from the offisial Next.js page: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

---

I tried `beforeInteractive` also, it also does not fire, why?

Comment: Where are you using the `Script` component? Have you checked the official GTM example https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Do you mean this iframe solution? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager/pages/_document.js

Comment: `Script` component is used in `_document.tsx`